# Set AppCompatBackgroundTint programmatically

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've got a TextView that I want to set the background tint of. My app has a `minSDK` of `19` so I've used AppCompatTextView with the `app:backgroundTint` parameter used to set the tint declaratively. I would like to programmatically change the tint, but the `setSupportBackgroundTintList()` method isn't accessible outside the library group. How can I change this value from an Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code for androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView:

> This should be accessed via
>
> `ViewCompat#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View, ColorStateList)`

So, write this:

```
AppCompatTextView textView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)
ColorStateList colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.your_state_list);
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(textView, colorStateList);
```

Comment: I'm not using androidx (currently using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`), and it doesn't have the method documented with those parameters, but this works! Am I looking at the wrong documentation?

Comment: Hm, not sure. I looked for sources for the old `appcompat` versions of these classes and I'm not finding `setSupportBackgroundTintList()` in `AppCompatTextView`. Maybe the sources available online are wrong?

Comment: I'll have to look into the documentation when I have more time. But this solution works, so thanks!